# Writing AutoIncrement for primary key in CodeFirst

Tags: sql-server, database, class, primary-key, ef-code-first

I am using CodeFirst in my project. One of the things I am learning is how I can design my tables by first writing classes. My question is - how can I classify the primary key [key] Id, as an auto increment field. So that when a record is created (or a row in the table) the primary key is auto generated. How do I do this in codefirst while writing class definition. Thanks for the help.

```
 public class NewTable
{   
   //Looking for something like [AutoIncrement][key] for Id field etc...
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `string` auto increment? That's not gonna work.

Use `int` instead, and the PK will be an `identity` column by default. You don't need the `[Key]` attribute either; EF will infer that because the property is called `Id`.

Comment: Thats an int.. mistake. Thank you..I tried not putting the [key] .. but it still shows Id is null... its not getting generated .. auto

Comment: Did you let EF generate the DB? If you did, the column should be identity in SQL Server. If you did not, go ahead and change it.